# Facebook og tags - property 'fb:app_id' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, tags, share, facebook-sharer

Looked around on stackoverflow and found some posts about this but no solution that works for me...

I get this error on [developers.facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/).

```
Object at URL 'http://www.sitename.be/' of type 'website' is invalid because the given value '119334461484878' for property 'fb:app_id' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'.
```

Although the id provided is correct.. I never really used this before but so far everything works except the sharing for detail pages. 
When I share the url I get the correct info in facebook, but when I share a blogpost (url.com/blog/blogpost) I still get the information from the main page...

I think this might be because of the error I get but if it is not this, how do I fix the detailed page sharing?

```
    <meta property="og:url"           content="@yield('url')" />
    <meta property="og:type"          content="article" />
    <meta property="og:title"         content="page title blabla" />
    <meta property="og:description"   content="Lorem ipsum" />
    <meta property="og:image"         content="http://www.sitename.be/img/share.jpg" />

    <meta property='fb:admins'        content='myPersonalFBId'>
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="119334461484878" />
```

Thanks

Comment: did you submit your app?

Comment: Yes. A workaround that I have found now is that I created a new profile, made that profile admin of the page and created a new app with that account. For some reason I can't do it with my personal FB account..